# How to run existing Selenium scripts in TOSCA

Tags: selenium, tosca

How to run existing Selenium scripts in TOSCA?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have used JUnit script, while running getting the below error. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at Tricentis.Automation.SpecialExecutionTasks.SeleniumExecution.SimpleProcessHandler.RunProgram(String exe, String args, String& processOutput, String& processError) .

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, TOSCA uses C# as a scripting language. If your selenium scripts are developed in C#, then you'll able to run those in TOSCA.

Comment: I have used JUnit script, while running getting the below error. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Tricentis.Automation.SpecialExecutionTasks.SeleniumExecution.SimpleProcessHandler.RunProgram(String exe, String args, String& processOutput, String& processError)             .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Selenium module from TBox automation tools under Tosca.

The folder Selenium contains the following Modules:

Start Selenium Server

Run Selenium Scripts

These Modules can be used to start Selenium test cases directly from Tosca Commander. NUnit or JUnit 4 test cases are supported. You can run DLL and JAR files which contain Selenium 1 (RemoteControl) and Selenium 2 (WebDriver) test cases. For more info [see here](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=11.2.0&url=engines_3.0/automation_tools/selenium/selenium.htm)